# What is the interpretation of 2nd Q-Q plot in diagnostic plot in regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, residuals, qq-plot

With reference to http://analyticspro.org/2016/03/07/r-tutorial-how-to-use-diagnostic-plots-for-regression-models/

in the post to correct the problem of curved residual pattern a qudratic term is added which screws up the Q-Q plot. Can someone explain the interpretation and whether the 2nd model with quadratic term is acceptable ?

Comment: The link is broken, making the question incomprehensible.